# I need javascript for to enable display on toggled list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a ul list that I added toggle to using Javascript
and set display to none using CSS and everything is working fine.
I am looking for the javacript to make the link display (not collapsed) on the next page
when the links under the parent menu is clicked. So they are collapsed by default but when any of the links
clicked and the page loads, the links would not be collapsed as it was initially when the page was first visited.
Here's my current markup

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Main Title
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">link 1 </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">link 2 </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">link 3 </a>
            </li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>

<style>
    ul li ul {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $('li').click(function (e) {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So you want the list to be expanded on the next page if it was expanded on the first page? Use sessionStorage, localStorage or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery Code**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hideshow").hide();     //By Default li is hide

        $("ul").click(function(){
            $("#hideshow").slideToggle(1000);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**HTML Code**

```
 <body>
    <ul><li>Hide </li></ul>
    <ul id="hideshow">
      <li><a href="#">link 1 </a></li>
      <li> a href="#">link 2 </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 3 </a></li>
    </ul>
    </body>
```